# R: How can I convert columns of a data.frame to x[,1] and x[,2]?

Tags: r, object, matrix

I'm trying to use the R function ZYmediate from R.R. Wilcox's robust functions ("Introduction to Robust Estimation and Hypothesis Testing"), as implemented in the **WRS** package hosted at this GitHub repo: https://github.com/nicebread/WRS

The ZYmediate function is specified as follows:

```
ZYmediate(x,y,nboot=2000,alpha=.05,kappa=.05,SEED=TRUE,xout=FALSE,outfun=out)
```

Documentation states that x[,1] is predictor, x[,2] is mediator variable, and y is outcome variable.

If I have a data.frame with three columns (mediator, predictor, and outcome), how can I convert the predictor and the mediator columns of the data.frame to an x object where the predictor is x[,1] and the mediator is x[,2]?

Currently, I am trying to get this to work with a data set from the "mediation" package. Here is how I am importing it:

```
install.packages("mediation")
library("mediation")
set.seed(2014)
data("framing", package = "mediation")
# Mediator = framing$emo, predictor = framing$treat, outcome = framing$cong_mesg
```

Thinking this might be a matrix object, I tried

```
x <- matrix(framing$cong_mesg, framing$emo)
```

But it tells me "data length [265] is not a sub-multiple or multiple of the number of rows [7]"

I also tried

```
x <- matrix(framing$cong_mesg, framing$emo)
```

But when I run ZYmediate(x,y) it tells me "Error in t(Z) %*% matrix(1/n, n,1) : requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments. In addition: Warning message:In cbind(x, y): number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)"

What function should I be using? Thanks! I'm still learning R, so forgive me if this question is trivial.

Comment: You misspelled the column names from the looks of it. `framing$cong_mesg` versus `framing$cond_mesg`. Also, check out `?matrix` for the arguments for matrix - you might be looking to do a `cbind()`

Comment: @ialm Please see recent edits. Thanks!

Comment: If your data has predictor as first column and mediator as second column, then you already have what you need - but just don't pass the response (3rd column) to the `x` argument. Try `ZYmediate(x = your_data[, 1:2], y = your_data[, 3], ...)`

Comment: That assumes it expects a data frame, if it needs a matrix, then switch to `ZYmediate(x = as.matrix(your_data[, 1:2]), y = your_data[, 3], ...)`

Comment: But you don't need the object to be named `x` in your workspace, you just need to pass your data, whatever it is called, to the `x` argument of `ZYmediate()`.

Comment: @Gregor: I tried ZYmediate(x = as,matrix(framing[, 11:7]), y = framing[, 7]) It tells me "Error in solve.default(Sigma0) : Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[6,6] = 0". So I guess that's satisfying the variable requirements. I'll have to try this with another data set next to see if it's an issue with the framing data.

Comment: Why are you giving it **so many columns**? It is asking for 1 single column  as a predictor, the first column, `x[, 1]` and one single column as mediator, the second column, `x[, 2]`. If you give it `framing[, 11:7]` that is *5 columns*. It wants two. Then, when you give it `y = [, 7]` you are giving your response column, `framing[7]` in both `x` and `y`, so of course it's singular! If `framing[, 7]` is your response, use `y = framing[, 7]` but **don't include your response column in `x`!!** It's a separate argument, `y`!

Comment: And without looking at the documentation, I have no idea what it will do when you give `x` more than two columns. What you have in your question: "*Documentation states that x[,1] is predictor, x[,2] is mediator variable*" strongly implies that the `x` argument should have only 2 columns, the first column a predictor, the second column a mediator.

Comment: @Gregor I didn't realize that that was how the colon (:) operated. Got it, and it seems to be working now!